# Horizontal tree arrows not aligned properly

Tags: tikz-arrows, forest, trees

I have taken some code from multiple places and pasted them together in order to show the structure of a folder and its underlying folders. I got it working, however the last arrow (from month to day) of the tree became slightly crooked as I changed to another latex template.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how one would go about fixing such a problem?

Code:

```
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

{\small
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={->},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=10mm,minimum height=8mm, % node shape
        l sep=5mm % level distance
}
  [Root folder
    [Customer id
        [Machine id
            [Year
                [Month
                    [Day]]]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\caption{File hierarchy}
\label{fig:filehierarchy}
\end{figure}
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Please post compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely because only the last node has a descender, i.e. a letter that goes below the baseline (the `y`). One fix is to add `font=\strut` to the tree settings:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\small
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
        grow=0,reversed, % tree direction
        parent anchor=east,child anchor=west, % edge anchors
        edge={->},outer sep=+1pt, % edge/node connection
        rounded corners,minimum width=10mm,minimum height=8mm,font=\strut, % node shape <-- added font=\strut
        l sep=5mm % level distance
}
  [Root folder
    [Customer id
        [Machine id
            [Year
                [Month
                    [Day]]]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\caption{File hierarchy}
\label{fig:filehierarchy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, what does the font=\strut parameter do exactly?

Comment: @MilanvanDijck `font` is intended for adding font changing commands to a node, e.g. `font=\bfseries` to make the node bold, but I suppose it inserts the argument at the start of the node text. A `\strut` is a zero-width box with (a font dependent) height and depth. So inserting a `\strut` in every node means that all the nodes have equal height and depth (i.e. they go the same distance below the baseline), instead of just the last one having some depth, and the rest zero depth.

Comment: the same result you can obtain with `rounded corners,minimum width=10mm,minimum height=8mm,text depth=0.25ex, % node shape`

Comment: For this method, I'd be inclined to use `delay={content/.wrap value=\strut#1,},`, to avoid abusing `font`. However, I guess if it doesn't do anything untoward, it should hopefully do no harm. `font` does whatever it does in Ti*k*Z. This isn't a Forest key that I know of. If you are not going to use them for alignment, you can make the code more flexible using `parent` and `children` rather than `west` and `east`. (But I don't think there's a `mid children` or `mid parent`, so I can't do this, I don't think :(.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably to change the `parent` and `child` anchors to use `mid`, which Ti*k*Z provides for aligning things with variable heights and depths.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0, % tree direction
    parent anchor=mid east,  % edge anchors
    child anchor=mid west,
    edge+={->}, % edge/node connection
    outer sep=+1pt,
    rounded corners, % node shape
    minimum width=10mm,
    minimum height=8mm,
    l sep'=5mm % level distance <= no it isn't - it is the minimum level separation, which is not necessarily the dimension actually used
  }
  [Root folder
    [Customer id
      [Machine id
        [Year
          [Month
            [Day]]]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: aligned arrows]

This avoids enlarging nodes unnecessarily, which might be undesirable in some cases.